# barcodescanner library from dm77 using front camera

Tags: android, android-camera, barcode

I'm using the [barcodescanner library from dm77](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) and it works just great.

Now I would like to use the **front camera** instead of the rear camera.

I can't find a way to do so, has anyone found a way to achieve this?

I made this work with ZXing native libraries, using `Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)`, but I now would like to use the other library that uses ZBar instead.

DM77's barcodescanner uses [CameraUtils](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/blob/master/core/src/main/java/me/dm7/barcodescanner/core/CameraUtils.java)'s `getCameraInstance()` to get the camera, which uses `Camera.open()`. I would like to change that behavior wihout having to clone and modify the original sources.

Comment: Were you really able to get this to work with ZXing? I'm trying to do something similar(scan barcodes using the front facing camera), but wasn't sure as people have been getting mixed results. Please let me know! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lokks like this is not possible without altering the sources.

I'll use the "raw" ZBar library or clone that dmyy's library.